# How to get the frame name from var

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, tkinter

Can we get the frame name from a variable?

ex:

```
var=myLabel

 link1 = Label(var, width=48, text=mylbl, justify=LEFT, anchor="center", fg="blue",cursor="hand")
link1.grid(row=i, column=0, sticky="ne", pady=2)
```

i tried like that but it dont work, i even put in a str(var) to try to force it but nothing, is there a way to do it?

i have 10 Label and i could just do a loop if i could get the Label name from a var, instead i have 100 line of code when i could only have 10.

thanks

EDIT(for ex)

```
global varLnkOrder
varLnkOrder = ""
varLbook = open("Confs/bookmarks.txt", "r").readlines()




for line in varLbook:
        if ":stathomelib" in line:
            varLnkOrder = "stathomelib"
            i = 0
        elif ":stathomedoc" in line:
            varLnkOrder = "stathomedoc"
            i = 0

#this part i could just do a func call by the if statement above with the specs

 if "stathomelib" in varLnkOrder:
        if len(line) > 1:
            titul, urlbook = line.split('<=>')
            if len(titul) > 1:
                link1 = Label(stathomelib, width=48, text=titul, justify=LEFT, anchor="center", fg="blue",
                          cursor="hand")
                link1.grid(row=i, column=0, sticky="ne", pady=2)
                link1.bind("<Button-1>", lambda e, urlbook=urlbook: webbrowser.open(urlbook.rstrip()))
                i += 1
                line == ""

    elif "stathomedoc" in varLnkOrder:
        if len(line) > 1:
            titul, urlbook = line.split('<=>')
            if len(titul) > 1:
                link1 = Label(stathomedoc, width=48, text=titul, justify=LEFT, anchor="center", fg="blue",cursor="hand")
                link1.grid(row=i, column=0, sticky="ne", pady=2)
                link1.bind("<Button-1>", lambda e, urlbook=urlbook: webbrowser.open(urlbook.rstrip()))
                i += 1
                line = ""
```

i need something like this:

```
frm123 = Label(tabmain1, text='')
frm123.pack(side='top', fill='x', expand=False)
frm456 = Label(tabmain1, text='')
frm456.pack(side='bottom', fill='x', expand=False)
global var
if varn==1:
    var="frm123"
    mylbl="first"
    buidd(var)
elif varn==2:
    var="frm456"
    mylbl = "second"
    buidd(var)


def buildd(var):
    link1 = Label(var, width=48, text=mylbl, justify=LEFT, anchor="center", fg="blue", cursor="hand")
    link1.grid(row=i, column=0, sticky="ne", pady=2)
```

Comment: Can you please show us more code, like how did you declare `myframe`, the actual `for` loop? The code you have should create a new `Label` widget and put it inside the `myframe` `Frame`

Comment: @TheLizzard hope its easier this way

Comment: We can't run your code, and it seems to be more complex than necessary for the question. Plus, it doesn't even create a frame even though you seem to be asking about frames. If you do `var = Frame(...)`, both `str(var)` and `var.winfo_name()` return variations of the widget name. It's not really clear why that doesn't work for you, or why you need the name at all. For the most part the name isn't very useful in tkinter.

Comment: its a label... im sorry not a frame, its a label

Comment: You need to pass *the actual widget* - `var=frm123` for example - not a string that happens to be equal to the name of a variable referring to the widget.

Comment: done, dont know why it didnt work before... thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the actual widget - var=frm123 for example - not a string that happens to be equal to the name of a variable referring to the widget. – jasonharper 59 mins ago